# How to log from a shader in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es

I have been trying to see what is happening in my shader at run time. But I have been unable to find a way to log the contents of shader variables to the console. I know the shader runs on the GPU so logging is bound to be more complicated. If Possible? How do I log from a shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to log from a shader. If trying to debug, you just have to use the color output to tell what's going on.

Comment: Yup, you'll get pretty familiar with seeing psychedelic scenes by the time you've debugged a few shaders. In addition to this, I might suggest you watch the WWDC videos for what's new in the OpenGL ES tools in iOS 6.0. Can't say more because of the NDA, but there's something in there that can help you here.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/) library. You can use to write your shader code in C++, and use your tools of choice to debug it. It doesn't cover everything in OpenGL, but it is very easy to use and will give you a very good idea of what's going on in your shader.